# Django offset-naive date from DB

Tags: python, django

I just switched from django 1.3.7 to 1.4.22 (on my way to updating to a higher version of django). I am using USE_TZ=True and TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Bucharest'. The problem that I am encountering is a DateTimeField from DB (postgres) that holds the value 2015-01-08 10:02:03.076+02 (with timezone) is read by my django as 2015-01-08 10:02:03.076000 (without timezone) even thou USE_TZ is True.
Any ideea why this might happen? I am using python 2.7.12 AMD64.

Thanks,
Virgil

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to logout once and log in again in the app for it to work. Thanks.